# Read k element from a list in xml using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to read the k element from xml using JAXB but I cannot find a solution. Has someone an idea? My xml file looks like this :

```
<supplier>
    <material>
        <materialId>0-MAT-1-LIC</materialId>
        <name>Material 1</name>
        <quantity>100</quantity>
    </material>
    <material>
        <materialId>1-MAT-1-LIC</materialId>
        <name>Material 2</name>
        <quantity>123</quantity>
    </material>
    <material>
        <materialId>3-MAT-1-LIC</materialId>
        <name>Material 3</name>
        <quantity>1343</quantity>
    </material>
    <material>
        <materialId>4-MAT-1-LIC</materialId>
        <name>Material 4</name>
        <quantity>1323</quantity>
    </material>
    <material>
        <materialId>5-MAT-1-LIC</materialId>
        <name>Material 5</name>
        <quantity>1234</quantity>
    </material>
    <material>
        <materialId>6-MAT-1-LIC</materialId>
        <name>Material 6</name>
        <quantity>12</quantity>
    </material>
</supplier>
```

I was able to map the xml to the java object but I need for example only the 4th element and not the hole list. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just iterate through the list of material objects and retrieve the 4th element? I assume you already have a List<Material> object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already mapped the xml to java object, you should have a `List` of material. You can invoke a `.get(index)` on that list. E.g. if you want to get the 4th element and the object name for the list is materialList, the code would be like this: `materialList.get(3);` Index 3 will give you the 4th element in the list.

However, if you only need to work with the 4th element then there is no need to convert the whole xml into a java object. You can use xpath for that. Xpath for the given sample xml to fetch 4th material will be `(/supplier/material)[4]`

Comment: I don't want to get the entire list in java. I have more than 1000 entries into the xml so it would be inefficient.

Comment: I completely agree. For that, you can use Xpath. Updated the answer